# Windows Mobile Device centre.. Connecting each time

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5, activesync

Does anybody know if it's possible, that each time a winodws mobile device is connected, instead of having to click 'Connect without setting up your device' The device automatically connects and is able to function?

So instead of seeing this screen each time a device is connected.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7dwr0xgwx0dgybs/first.png

This screen is shown instead 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/x0l7qmy7nmk3qyu/second.png

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while, so I've not tested this under Win7 (meaning YMMV), but you used to be able to put ActiveSync into "Guest Only" mode for a PC and it would always just connect without asking about a partnership.  The only downside is that it won't auto-sync contacts, etc. - though in many cases you don't need or want that anyway.

Just set the following registry key *on the PC*.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows CE Services]
"GuestOnly"=dword:00000001
```

Answer (score 2):

To bypass this and connect as a guest account automatically change the following reg settings on your PC:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run] from %windir%\WindowsMobile\wmdc.exe to %windir%\WindowsMobile\wmdcbase.exe
```

This eliminates the popup window each time you sync the device.

And this defaults to connect as Guest:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows CE Services] "GuestOnly"=dword:00000001
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not do it, but I believe if you bond the mobile device with the PC, you will, in fact, see the 2nd screen when you plug the device up.

I used to do that, but we have about 20 different devices that I have to maintain. You'd think I only had to do it once per device, so only 20 times, but some bozo employee would leave a device off a charger for a month and bring it to me all dead and zeroed out. In that case, you are out of luck and you have to bond the device to the PC again.

Comment: If you set the PC up to do guest-only connection it will never ask.